# Content Search Web Part 'modified by' as a second line

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-schema

I am trying to get the element 'Modified by' to display in a CSWP.

If I rightclick on Modified by column I get that the real name for this is 'Editor'.

I have tried with Editor and with a mapping of modified by (ows_Modified_x0020_By).

In both cases I get the Modified By as written in the properties of Word, Excel and PowerPoint.

Is there a way to get the element Modified by as per library column (example someone who does not edit the document but changes the metadata columns in the library)

Comment: Use the managed property `EditorOWSUSER` or else map the crawled property `ows_q_USER_Editor` to a `RefinableStringXX` and check

Comment: I have tried ows_q_USER_Editor to refinable string and so far nothing has changed, the second line is empty. Maybe it will appear after some more minutes. By chance do you also know the equivalent for Modified? I have tried LastModifiedTime but again it gives me the last modified of the Word Document and not of the entry line

Comment: For modified date, you can use `LastModifiedTimeForRetention` managed property or you can map `ows_Modified` to a `RefinableDateXX` and check

Comment: ows_q_USER_Editor  gives me the complete full user name + some codes, which i do not need. But still, it carries the Word document editor and not the person who edited metadata

Comment: I hate to say this but it works in my tenant :( , gives me the correct display name of the user who modified  the document. Dont think it matters though, but i mapped the properties from the tenant admin site. Also, does the `RefinableDateXX ` work for document modified date ?